# Adding none editable new row to SWT/jface table

Tags: java, swt

Is there an option to make one row in swt table not editable after adding it ,(and the other rows still editable)

I am adding new row in this way.

```
Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
tableViewer.add(rowElement);
table.setTopIndex(table.getItemCount());
table.select(table.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the new element do your model rather than to the viewer itself?

Comment: Yes i do it ,by using tableViewer.setInput() but the issue how can make specific row not editable ,working in the rows level and not in the column levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using your `TableViewer` with an `EditingSupport` (if not, read [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_editor)).

The `EditingSupport` has a method `canEdit(Object object)`. You can use the following to prevent editing of a given cell:

```
@Override
protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    YourObject obj = (YourObject)element;
    if(IT_IS_THE_ELEMENT_YOU_SEEK)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: do you mean that i need to create my customEditingSupport and add it to the TableViewer , is there an option to it during adding the row.
how can i get set the EditingSupport on the tableviewer

Comment: @user1205079 Why do you want to add it just in this case? It doesn't hurt to add it directly after your viewer declaration.

Comment: the issue that i once the table is created it contains rows, that i want prevent the user from edit them, and i just want to give the user ability to add new rows that can be editable,so the table contains rows that are not editable, and new rows that are editable

Comment: @user1205079 Then set a public static boolean variable as soon as the user adds it's first row and check this variable within the `EditingSupport`.